# Running (local) Azure worker role from network share

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-worker-roles

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Azure development (or really, anything having to do with Windows and .Net), so please bear with me...

---

I don't use Windows day-to-day so for this project I set up a Windows 7 VirtualBox instance in which to do development. I have my host OS's code directory shared with the VM and the VM has it mounted as a network share (which shows up as `E:\` or `\\VBOXSVR\` depending on... ?).

The problem I'm running into is that when I try to get my worker role to run on the Azure Compute Emulator it dies with the following error:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Critical: 201 : Role entrypoint could not be created:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file://\\VBOXSVR\XXX\YYY\csx\Debug\roles\WorkerRole\approot\WorkerRole.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
File name: 'file://\\VBOXSVR\XXX\YYY\csx\Debug\roles\WorkerRole\approot\WorkerRole.dll' ---> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.CreateRoleEntryPoint(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType roleTypeEnum)
```

Following [that link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569) gives you a page that says to add:

```
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
```

to your config file. I added it to the worker role's app.config, leaving me with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
    ... 
</configuration>
```

but, when I try to run it, I get the same error message.

Comment: I also have this situation on VS2012 almost a year later. Same question: what's the right way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't running my Azure project on a VM but the source code on the host machine. But as far as I know the azure local emulator needs administrator privilege. This might be the reason I guess, since I tried to debug an application on my host machine from the VM, which just open the solution on the share folder in VS, but failed.

Comment: I've got the Azure VM running... Visual Studio forces you to run with Administrator privileges to be able to start it.

Comment: Yes I know that. You must run as administrator to run the azure local emu. But I have the experience that open my source code through share folder on VM and debug it, failed. This is why I guess you don't have enough permission to work on VM, not only for azure project maybe.